# Rxjs retryWhen not calling [angular 5]

Tags: angular, rxjs

i have a probleme to subscribe on `retryWhen` with the angular HttpClient.

I use angular `5.2.11`, rxjs `5.5.11`.

```
 this._httpClient.get('myUrl').retryWhen((errors) => {
  console.log('retryWhen', errors);
  return errors.scan((count, error) => {
    if (count >= retryOptions.retries) {
      throw error;
    }
    return count + 1;
  }, 0)
    .delay(retryOptions.delay)
    .takeWhile(count => count <= retryOptions.retries);
});
```

When i do this, the `console.log` or breakpoint is never called.

I have imported operators like this.
`import { retryWhen } from 'rxjs/operators/retryWhen';`
And also 
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/retryWhen';`

But the result is the same, when i have a error during the request, he made a infinite loop

Thx

Comment: try `this._httpClient.get('myUrl').pipe(.retryWhen((errors) => {........)`

Answer (score 0):

I fact, that's work sorry !

I haven't saw, my collegue update the code, and add a Http interceptor who return always an error..